# org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.getManifest(org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject, org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiveConfiguration)

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven, jboss-developer-studio

I referred to some of the related posts but it did not solved my issue. Because i am using maven-jar-plugin-2.4 jar.

I am using JBoss Developer Studio 7.1.1 GA IDE and i am trying to build my code. From command prompt my build was successfull. When i tried to compile my code inside JBDS 7.1.1 below error is thrown

org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.getManifest(org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject, org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiveConfiguration) pom.xml /csi-rcs-connector  line 1  Maven Configuration Problem

My POM looks like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.aaa.csi</groupId>
    <artifactId>csi</artifactId>
    <version>2.33-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../csi/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>csi-rcs-connector</artifactId>
  <packaging>rar</packaging>
  <name>RCS JCA Connector</name>
  <description>JCA-compliant connector for accessing RCS</description>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.aaa.csi</groupId>
      <artifactId>csi-common</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.aaa.csi</groupId>
      <artifactId>csi-rcs-common</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-rar-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>rar</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>rar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <includeJar>false</includeJar>
              <rarSourceDirectory>target/classes</rarSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>

  </build>

  <profiles>

    <profile>
      <id>stage-dist</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>

  </profiles>

</project>
```

My parent pom file looks like

```
<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

<pluginManagement>

  <plugins>

    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <argLine>-enableassertions</argLine>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-packaging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-rar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>delete-dist-dir</id>
          <phase>clean</phase>
          <configuration>
            <tasks>
              <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
            </tasks>
          </configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>create-dist-dir</id>
          <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
          <configuration>
            <tasks>
              <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
            </tasks>
          </configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>integration-test</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>hard-deploy</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <serverName>${jboss.server.id}</serverName>
            <deploySubDir>${jboss.deploy.dir}</deploySubDir>
            <fileName>${deployable.file.name}</fileName>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <generateReports>false</generateReports>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>create-remote-resources</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>bundle</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>copy-remote-resources</id>
          <phase>pre-site</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>process</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <resourceBundles>
          <resourceBundle>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</resourceBundle>
        </resourceBundles>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.xsd</include>
          <include>**/*.wsdl</include>
        </includes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <configuration>
        <filesets>
          <fileset>
            <directory>src/site/resources</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>**/schema/**</include>
            </includes>
          </fileset>
        </filesets>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

  </plugins>

</pluginManagement>

<plugins>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-rar-plugin</artifactId>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-packaging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
  </plugin>

</plugins>
```

My .m2 folder consists of "maven-jar-plugin-2.4.jar"

I got stuck with this. Any help appreciated. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Could you upgrade to devstudio 10.1 and see if the new version of m2e in there fixes the issue or at least throws a more helpful error message? devstudio 7 is several years old.